# React native track player fails to add songs to playlist

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-track-player

I am working on a music player in react native and have been using the package react-native-track-player. I have so far not had a problem with the package in android. but when I try to run it on ios I get the error 
`You attempted to set the key`0`with the value`

```
{"id":"0",
 "url":{"uri":"https://urltosong.mp3"},
 "artwork":"https://url_to_artwork.jpg",
 "artist":"author",
 "title":"song titile"
}
```

`on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.`

The code that generate the error is

```
async function togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrack == null) {
      await TrackPlayer.reset();
      await TrackPlayer.add(playlist); //this was never adding and die silently
      await TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
            await TrackPlayer.add(playlist); //adding this line the error above appeared
            await TrackPlayer.play();
            //console.warn(TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack())
    }
  }
```

I am using this version of the package `"react-native-track-player": "^2.0.0-rc13",`

I don't know if there is something I am missing. I will appreciate your help in fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your track to this:

```
{"id":"0",
 "url":"https://urltosong.mp3",
 "artwork":"https://url_to_artwork.jpg",
 "artist":"author",
 "title":"song titile"
}
```

Urls should be either a `string` or a `Resource Object`